# How can I emit a list of values from a Mapper or Reducer?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hbase, hdfs

I have a file that contains some geophysical data (seismic data) and I am reading these files from the local file system and storing them as Hadoop Sequential files in HDFS.

Now I want to write a MapReduce job that can read the values from these Sequential files and store them into an HBase table. These files are not simply flat files. Instead they consist of many pieces, where each piece is a block of 240 bytes and has several fields. Each field can either be a short or an integer. I am using the block number as the key and a byte array of 240 bytes (which contains all the fields) as the value of Sequential files. So each Sequential file has all the blocks as byte arrays and their block number.

My question is, while processing such a file, how can I read each 240 byte block, read individual fields and emit all the fields in one shot once a 240 bytes block is done? Suppose I have a file that has 1000 blocks. So in my MapReduce program I have to read these 1000 blocks one at a time, extract each field (short or int) and emit all the fields as the result of one Map.

I need some help, regarding this.

Answer (score 0):

Just to make sure, you want to read each `240 bytes` blocks, emit the block number as the key and the byte array as value? I think you'll have to extend the default `SequenceFileInputFormat`. I'm not exactly sure how Sequence File works, or what their structure is like (sorry), but I was trying to read entire contents of a file to emit as output value, and the way I did it was to extend `FileInputFormat`. Perhaps you can take a look at the source code for `SequenceFileInputFormat` and see if there is a way to make an `InputSplit` every `240 bytes` (if your data is structured), or at some delimiter.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Zhi An : thanks for the reply..actually i already have the sequential file (block no as the key and a 240 byte array that contains the whole block)